# Error importing smptlib

Tags: python, importerror, smtplib

So I know I have to import smtplib first, but I am getting this error:

```
>>> import smtplib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\JH.LENOVO-D7A4458D.006\Desktop\Python\Rozrobené\email.py", line 5, in <module>
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
ImportError: No module named 'email.mime'; 'email' is not a package
```

I tried to re-install whole python, but it´s still same. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you appended the Python Path environment variable to include the path to `email.py`? You can check using `sys.path`.

Comment: You should rename your `email.py`  to something else because it shadows the `email` package.